# Как с помощью lodash вытащить элемент

Tags: javascript, lodash

Всем привет, не до конца разобралась с lodash
Подскажите, пожалуйста как вытащить из данных элемент

Массив

```
const arr = [
  {
    label: 'Элемент 1'
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Элемент 2'
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Нужно получить объект { id: 2 } id которого равно 2 (item.id === 2) 
Хотелось бы сделать это одной строкой

Функция рабочая, хотелось бы с помощью lodash как то написать в одну строку

```
export const getData = (arr, id) => {
  const findObj = _.find(arr, { insideArr: [{ id }] })
  return _.find(findObj, item => item. id === id)
}
```

Comment: Я так и не понял что нужно получить и при чём тут java-stream?

Comment: Ошиблась меткой. 
Функция рабочая, хотелось бы с помощью lodash как то написать в одну строку
`export const getData = (arr, id) => {
  const findObj = _.find(arr, { insideArr: [{ id }] })
  return _.find(findObj, item => item. id === id)
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = [
  { label: 'Элемент 1', insideArr: [{ id: 1 }] },
  { label: 'Элемент 2', insideArr: [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] },
]

console.log(_.find(_.flatten(_.map(a, 'insideArr')), { id: 2 })) // lodash
console.log(a.flatMap(x => x.insideArr).find(x => x.id === 2))   // pure ES2019
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему именно lodash?
Так не пойдёт?

```
const obj = arr.find((el) => {
    return el.insideArr.find((el) => {
        return el.id === 2
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

с  учетом различных возможных значений id , а так же возможности содержания в insideArr нескольких объектов то думаю такой вариант наиболее подходящий:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    label: 'Элемент 1',
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Элемент 2',
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 2,
      }
    ]
  },
]

function getItemFromId(arr,id){
  return arr.filter(item=> _.get(item,'insideArr',[]).find(item=>_.get(item,'id',null)===id)
  )
}
console.log(getItemFromId(arr,2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот вариант Вас устроит:

```
_.find(arr, { 'insideArr': [{ 'id': 2 }] })
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    label: 'Элемент 1',
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 1,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Элемент 2',
    insideArr: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Abraham',
      },
      {
        garbage: { no: 'problem' }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const res = _.find(arr, { 'insideArr': [{ 'id': 2 }] })
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[источник](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/591#issuecomment-46786817) Переданный вместо предиката объект используется для проверки на **частичное** совпадение с искомым объектом коллекции (как подмножество свойств искомого объекта).

Comment: не будет работать если массив insideArr будет содержать не один объект а два  и так далее

Comment: Дополнил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня получилось с 2мя вложенными _.find